# Is it possible to get the transcripts for all the videos of a youtube channel using Javascript

Tags: next.js, youtube-api

I want to get all the transcripts for all the videos on a youtube channel. This is my code.

```js
async function getVideoTranscripts(videoId) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&videoId=${videoId}&key=${process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY}`
    );

    const captionIds = response.data.items.map((item) => item.id);

    // Step 2: Fetch transcripts for each caption
    const transcriptPromises = captionIds.map(async (captionId) => {
      try {
        const transcriptResponse = await axios.get(
          `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/${captionId}&key=${process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
          }
        );
        return transcriptResponse.data.body;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          `Error fetching transcript for caption ${captionId}:`,
          error
        );
        return null;
      }
    });

    const transcripts = await Promise.all(transcriptPromises);
    return transcripts.filter((transcript) => transcript !== null);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error fetching transcripts for video ${videoId}:`, error);
    return [];
  }
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

My API key has full permission from the console to make any request. I am not exactly sure why this is failing.

Comment: Is it your own YouTube channel?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison It is a Saas spplication that I am building. So, I want to build it in such a way that everyone with a youtube channel, can get all their transcripts